# How to delete a line from a textfile using java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, file-io, text-files

I wanted to delete a line from a textfile after asking the user what he/she wants to delete but I don't know what to do next in my code.

The textfile looks like this:

```
1::name::mobileNum::homeNum::fax::birthday::email::website::address // line the user wants to delete
2::name::mobileNum::homeNum::fax::birthday::email::website::address
3::name::mobileNum::homeNum::fax::birthday::email::website::address
```

Here's my code:

```
public static void readFromFile(String ans, String file) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    GetUserInput console = new GetUserInput();
    
    String checkLine = fileIn.readLine();
    
        while(checkLine!=null) {
            String [] splitDetails = checkLine.split("::");
            Contact details = new Contact(splitDetails[0], splitDetails[1], splitDetails[2], splitDetails[3], splitDetails[4], splitDetails[5], splitDetails[6], splitDetails[7], splitDetails[8]);
            checkLine = fileIn.readLine();
            
            
                if(ans.equals(splitDetails[0])) {
                    // not sure what the code will look like here.
                    // in this part, it should delete the line the user wants to delete in the textfile
                    
                }
        }
}
```

So the output of the textfile should be like this:

```
2::name::mobileNum::homeNum::fax::birthday::email::website::address
3::name::mobileNum::homeNum::fax::birthday::email::website::address
```

Also, I want the line number 2 and 3 to be adjusted to 1 and 2:

```
1::name::mobileNum::homeNum::fax::birthday::email::website::address
2::name::mobileNum::homeNum::fax::birthday::email::website::address
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Hint: you can't delete from a text file. Instead, you write the data that you want to keep (without the deleted data) in a new file, and then switch between the files and delete the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working code, assuming you are using Java >= 7:

```
public static void removeLine(String ans, String file) throws IOException {
    boolean foundLine = false;
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file));
            BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file + ".tmp"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("::", 2);
            if (tokens[0].equals(ans)) {
                foundLine = true;
            } else {
                if (foundLine) {
                    bw.write((Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) - 1) + "::" + tokens[1]);
                } else {
                    bw.write(line);
                }
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
    }
    Files.move(Paths.get(file + ".tmp"), Paths.get(file), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

It is not possible to delete a line from a file. What you need to do is read the existing file, write the contents you want to keep to a temporary file and then rename the temporary file to overwrite the input file.

Here, the temporary file is created in the same directory as the input file, with the extension `.tmp` added (note that you can also use [`Files.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) for this).

For each line that is read, we check if this is the line the user wants to delete.

- If it is, we update a boolean variable telling us that we just hit the line to be deleted and we do not copy this line to the temporary file.
- If it is not, we have a choice:

  - Either we did not yet hit the line to be deleted. Then we simply copy what we read to the temporary file
  - Or we did and we need to decrement the first number and copy the rest of the line to the temporary file.

The current line is splitted with the help of [`String.split(regex, limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) (it splits the line only two times, thereby creating an array of 2 Strings: first part is the number, second part is the rest of the line).

Finally, the temporary file overwrites the input file with [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) (we need to use the [`REPLACE_EXISTING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#REPLACE_EXISTING) option).